# How to ensure a thread change when doing async/await?

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, task-parallel-library

When doing `await` the `Task` could or could not be executed on the same thread. Usually, we just need to take this fact into design consideration. But I would like to do a test specifically for the thread change scenario - how do I ensure the rest of the async method (after await) is run on a different thread?

Possible solution:

```
    [Test]
    public void TestForThreadChange()
    {
        int threadIdBefore, threadIdAfter = 0;

        async Task AsyncFunction()
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"before - {threadIdBefore = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");
            await Task.Yield();
            Console.WriteLine($"after - {threadIdAfter = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");
        }

        AsyncFunction().Wait();

        Assert.That(threadIdBefore, Is.Not.EqualTo(threadIdAfter));
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure the significance. I think you had an async method or a collection then you could to Task.Wait, Task.WaitAll, Task.Any. I'm not sure if you can get to that low level thread event info without re-inventing some wheels. You could have the thread save into some thread-safe list it's own Id and you can monitor that.

Comment: _"we just need to take this fact into design consideration"_ -- not at all. Your code generally should not depend on where the continuation is executed. Indeed, since a nominally async task could complete synchronously (e.g. an async read where the data's already been buffered and is ready to be returned), you could never guarantee in general that a continuation runs in a different thread, nor would you want to.

Comment: @PeterDuniho, yes, that's in fact what I meant...you just need to know the thread change can happen and design the code it's not dependent on whether it runs on the same or different thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> how do I ensure the rest of the async method (after await) is run on a different thread?

First, ensure that you have call the method being tested from a thread-pool context. Some unit test frameworks do provide a single-threaded context. If that is the case, you'll want to wrap your testing code in an `await Task.Run(() => ...)`.

Then, mock the method being awaited and ensure it does an `await Task.Yield()`; this will ensure the `await` in the method under test will get an incomplete task, causing it to resume on a thread pool thread.

If you want to be *absolutely sure* that it resumes on a *different* thread pool thread, you'll need to block your unit test method on the method being tested, so that the current thread pool thread is blocked and not used to resume the method being tested.

Comment: Thanks, @stephen-cleary. That is exactly where I was heading. I just wasn't sure about the blocking part. Isn't it theoretically possible that even though the async method returns an incomplete task it still gets to be executed before the test method reaches the Wait()? I've added a possible solution to the answer.

Comment: @mivra: Yes, it can complete before it is awaited. Your solution doesn't guarantee the method will resume on a different thread; I'd recommend blocking on the task instead of using `await` to guarantee that it resumes on a different thread.

Comment: oh, simply use Wait() on the async function then. Do I get you right?

Comment: Yes. That way the thread that starts the async method is blocked and can't be used to resume it.

Answer (score 2):

You can't. Async pattern is designed to simplify the async (duh) code at the expense of some control. If you need to control thread creation, use Thread/ThreadPool.